# How to replace the a specific character in sed command which have predefine meaning?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have this text

```
" File: 'space folder' "
```

I want to replace this with only this

```
" space folder "
```

using sed or awk?
But when i try to do with it using sed it's not taking the command!
Does anyone have solution for this.

Comment: Can you add couple of more examples to clarify your task and also show your attempted command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your intent correctly, you need all text between single quotes; you can use this:

```
$ sed -r "s/^.*'([^']*)'.*$/\"\1\"/g" <<< "\" File: 'space folder' \""
"space folder"
$
```

Edit1: explanation

`command <<< string` => `<<<` indicates here string that is you pass a string to the command.

Our final string is this:

```
$ echo -e "\" File: 'space folder' \""
" File: 'space folder' "
$
```

since our string contains single quotes we use double quotes for `sed` command:

`-r` switch enables extended regular expression

`"s/^.*'([^']*)'.*$/\"\1\"/g"`

the above command substitutes the whole line with text present between single quotes.

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^`          matches start of line
- `.*`         matches 0 or more characters
- `'`          matches a literal single quote
- `([^']*)`    matches 0 or more characters that are not single quote
  and remembers it as a captured group with backreference number `\1`
- `'`          matches literal single quote
- `.*`         matches 0 or more chars
- `$`          matches end of line

Comment: Can you explain it little bit?

Comment: @J.K.Mahapatra added explanation